# Lexical Analyzer in Python

Tags: python, python-module

Is there a python module doing lexical analysis? (e.g. given a string, it analyzes whether it's a valid English word?)
    Thanks in advance!

Comment: Lexical analysis does not focus on one single word, but on a whole sentence or collection of sentences, parsing them and validating them according to a given grammar.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [nltk](http://nltk.org/)?

Comment: @NiklasR so what do you suggest then?

Comment: @lazyr not really but I will explore this. What I am really up to is know if a certain string "makes sense" (e.g. if it's found on the English dictionary., etc)

Comment: Your question would benefit if you gave examples of valid and invalid input strings. E.g. does "dog the green eat wanting" make sense?

Comment: @HansThen yes, the example you sited is a valid input string. Now I want to check if each word can be found on an English dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to collect a list of English words. On UNIX you could use /usr/share/dict/words. Read the list of words into python and do something like the following:

```
for word in my_string.split():
    if not word in word_list:
        print mystring, "is invalid"
    else
        print mystring, "is valid"
```

Comment: There are free word lists available over there, for instance http://mieliestronk.com/wordlist.html

Comment: Depending on the OP wants either a dictionary-like or a spell-checker-like word list may be more appropriate.